# Yii2. How to attach bootstrap Dropdown to a model?

Tags: model, yii2, html-lists, dropdown

I can place dropdown as following:

```
$form->field($model, 'filter')->dropDownList($items);
```

But it generates a select tag with options.

I need smth like this:

```
$form->field($model, 'filter')->widget(ButtonDropdown::className(),[])
```

But ButtonDropdown has no model property.
So how can I use ul list with model?

Comment: You could use something like Select2 yii2 widget for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a kartik`s widget "yii2-dropdown-x".

[Here is a link](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-dropdown-x)